# DIN Latching Relay

Tags: relay, latching-relay

I am new to relays, and trying to read up.
My needs are a relay that can control 230VAC min.10A(pref. 20A). It should be controlled by a 5VDC signal. One 5VDC *pulse*(0VDC->5VDC->0VDC) should trigger the relay to switch state, and then it should stay in that state until a new 5VDC pulse. It should preferably be mounted on a DIN rail.

Questions:

1) Am I looking for a 'Latching' Relay? (Pulse part)

2) Is there 'DIN Rail Socket/Holder' for relays intended for PCB mount?

3) And of course, is there any suggestion for a component fulfilling above?

Comment: are both pulses the same or is each different? (different wires / opposite polarity)

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes, you're looking for a latching relay.

The ones I'm familiar with have two coils with a common return.  You apply a pulse (usually 28V) to one coil to energize it, and a pulse to the other coil to de-energize it.

Answer (score 0):

1: If both pulses are the same you are looking for a ratchet, or alternating, relay.
if they are different you want a latching relay.

2: DIN enclosures are easily had, you can put anything inside... that doesn't magically make it safe or acceptable to inspectors.

3: Shopping assistance questions are off-topic. however there seem to be many more DIN mount relays with 12V, 24V, or 48V coils, you may need to boost your 5V signal a bit.